# Include Image in an email without attachments using java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to add an image to an email along with some text without having to attach the image in the email. Would this be possible ?

I have managed to do the following so far but it is sent with an attachment and also the image in the mail. I want it without an attachment but as a part of the mail

```
 `Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(emailID));
        message.setSubject("Password Reset");

                    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");


                    BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlPart.setContent("<html><body>Hi<img src=\"cid:the-img-1\"/></body></html>", "text/html");

    multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);


    BodyPart imgPart=new MimeBodyPart();

    // Loading the image
    DataSource ds=new FileDataSource("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\images.jpg");
    imgPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));

    //Setting the header
    imgPart.setHeader("Content-ID","the-img-1");

    multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);

    // attaching the multi-part to the message

    message.setContent(multipart);


        Transport.send(message);`
```

Comment: How else exactly do you propose to send the image?

Comment: As an inline content. I receive mails everyday with images in the mail and not as a content that refers to an attachment.

Comment: I suppose it's better use a url in img src

Comment: Ok. But for that wouldnt I need to have the image that can be accessed via a URL ?

Comment: Those "inline" images are attached. Examine the full message source for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct a [multipart/related](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendmpr) message.

Answer (score 0):

You will be need to construct an html based e-mail for that purpose.
There are plenty of examples that you can get on google for that.
One example is look at [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0504.html).

Note that image you want to send should be accessible over http to recipient. May be you can upload it on google drive or some image server

Comment: is having a reference to an attachment or using a URL the only way to embed an image ?

Comment: @Adarsh As far as I know, yes. After all, the image has to be somewhere : either on a publicly accessible site, or as a part of the mail. And that is what an attachement is. But I remember that old Windows mailers could use a RTF format (no mime attachement nor HTML then)  but no other mailer could then read the message...